# Não sei como calcular a distância

Tags: java

```
    Chromosome chromosome = new Chromosome();
    int[] gene = new int[6];
    gene[0] = 0;
    gene[1] = (int) (1 + (Math.random() * 3));
    gene[2] = (int) (4 + (Math.random() * 4));
    gene[3] = (int) (8 + (Math.random() * 4));
    gene[4] = (int) (12 + (Math.random() * 3));
    gene[5] = 15;

    chromosome.setGenes(gene);
    return chromosome;
}
```

Eu tenho esse método que insere números aleatórios, e com isso, eu preciso fazer outro método que calcula a distância total percorrida, que seria as 6 posições do array. Mas estou com dificuldade em ver uma forma de somar em outro método essa distância.

Comment: Você quer somar todos os indices desse array, é isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo, mas não sei como ter esses números em outro método

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar o método:

```
public static int somarArray(int[] array) {
    int valorTotal = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        valorTotal += array[i];
    }
    return valorTotal;
}
```

passando o seu array ex:

```
int[] gene = new int[6];
gene[0] = 0;
gene[1] = (int) (1 + (Math.random() * 3));
gene[2] = (int) (4 + (Math.random() * 4));
gene[3] = (int) (8 + (Math.random() * 4));
gene[4] = (int) (12 + (Math.random() * 3));
gene[5] = 15;

System.out.println(Classe.somarArray(gene));
```

Comment: Desculpa, mas eu não entendi essa chamada aqui: System.out.println(Classe.somarArray(gene));

Comment: É só para você ver a saida do método.

Comment: entendi, vou ver se vai funciona dentro do que eu preciso. Obrigada

Answer (score 0):

basta voce passar este objeto chromosome como referencia em outro metodo, assim vc tera acesso a tudo deste objeto.

exemplo:

```
private int somaDistancia (Chromosome chromosome){
int soma = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<chromosome.getGenes().length){
        //faz a manipulacao por ex:
        soma += chromosome.getGenes()[i];
    }
    return soma;
}
```

é isso q voce queria?

Comment: é basicamente isso, mas eu recebo por parâmetro um array de inteiros

Comment: seria a mesma coisa, mas ao inves de passsar o objeto por referencia apenas passaria o array.. a resposta do @matheus se enquadra melhor

Comment: sim, sim. mas eu não entendi a última chamada dele com system

Comment: aquela chamada apenas está tentando imprimir a soma.. somarArray é o nome do metodo q ele criou.. se voce criar o metodo dentro da mesma classe que este outro, no seu caso seria: System.out.println(somarArray(gene));

Comment: sim, agora eu entendi. Obrigada